# How animate insert/delete items in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, animation, stackpanel

I want to animate insert\delete the item in a StackPanel.
Eg: If new item inserted into collection all other items smoothly free space for new item and vice versa.

Can anyone suggest examples or ideas on this topic?

Comment: There is not much I-O events on a StackPanel.

Comment: Try attaching `FluidMoveBehavior` to your `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would animate the `Height` of objects

If adding, I would add items with a Height of 0 and animate it full size

If deleting, I would animate the height to 0 and remove the item when the height hits 0

This should work for most single-line items, although if your items contain multiple controls that are designed to stretch and fit whatever space is available to them, you might have to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I also thought about Height animation. But I wanted to see already implemented demo or samples for additional ideas. Do you known any demo or app with implemented insert/delete/sort operation for StackPanel or for any other container?

Comment: @Victor I don't, sorry. You could probably find some examples through Google though.